# Beautiful soup how to find the script tag of JS loaded page

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I used this code to get the content of this page
https://www.walmart.com/cp/976759

```js
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get("https://www.walmart.com/cp/976759", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

script = soup.find("script", {"id":"category"})

data = json.loads(script.get_text(strip=True))

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

the complete data is stored in a script tag with id as category as mentioned in this answer [lxml web-scraping is returning empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63089831/lxml-web-scraping-is-returning-empty-values/63090012?noredirect=1#comment111565734_63090012).

I have more pages to fetch and it appears they are loaded through javascript too. What are the methods of determining the script tag id that the site data is stored in ? for example how do I determine the script tag id of these links

https://www.walmart.com/cp/coffee/1086446?povid=976759+%7C+2018-12-26+%7C+Food%20Coffee%20Shop%20by%20Category%20Tile%201

and this one

https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/coffee/976759_1086446_1229654?povid=1086446+%7C++%7C+Coffee%20Bottle%20Coffee%20Featured%20Categories%20Collapsible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to match against attributes - and also to exclude attributes. I realise that the `script` tags you are looking for are all of type `application/json`, which I made the first filter, i.e. `soup.find_all('script', {'type': 'application/json'})`. Next, there are tags that start with `tb-djs-wlm`, which refer to several images. I exclude them using the regular expression `re.compile(r'^((?!tb-djs).)*$')`.

So, now we have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

session = requests.Session()

# your test urls
url1 = 'https://www.walmart.com/cp/coffee/1086446?povid=976759+%7C+2018-12-26+%7C+Food%20Coffee%20Shop%20by%20Category%20Tile%201'
url2 = 'https://www.walmart.com/browse/food/coffee/976759_1086446_1229654?povid=1086446+%7C++%7C+Coffee%20Bottle%20Coffee%20Featured%20Categories%20Collapsible'
url3 = 'https://www.walmart.com/cp/976759'
urls = [url1, url2, url3]

def find_tag(soup):
    script = soup.find('script', {'type': 'application/json', 'id':re.compile(r'^((?!tb-djs).)*$')})
    return script['id']

for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    print(find_tag(soup))

# category
# searchContent
# category
```

To get the content of the script you can use the `json` library and on the bs4 tag element and simply load it with `json.loads(script_soup.text)`

Comment: Thank You  and also thank you for the explanation. May you live long my friend!